# Find the covariance of indicator variables

Tags: probability, statistics

> [image]
>
> Show that $\text{Cov } (X_i, X_{i+1}) = 0.04687$

I know that $\text{Cov } (X_i, X_{i+1}) = E[X_iX_{i+1}] - E[X_i]E[X_{i+1}]$

We have $E[X_i X_{i+1}] = f(1, 1)$ where $f$ is the joint probability function.

So to calculate $f(1, 1)$ we need that $x_{i} \to x_{i+1} = \text{alternate}$ same with $x_{i+1}, x_{i+2}$

But I am not sure how to calculate it?

Would it be $f(1, 1) = 2*(0.75*0.25 + 0.75*0.25)$ accounting for cases $WL, LW$ and then for the $i+1 \to i+2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a turnover with $WL$ or $LW$ so $E[X_i]=E[X_{i+1}]=0.75 \times 0.25+0.25 \times 0.75= 0.375 = \frac{3}{8}$

You get a double turnover with $WLW$ or $LWL$ so $E[X_i X_{i+1}]=0.75 \times 0.25\times 0.75+0.25 \times 0.75\times 0.25= 0.1875= \frac{3}{16}$

which makes the covariance $E[X_i X_{i+1}]-E[X_i]E[X_{i+1}]=0.1875-0.375^2= 0.046875 = \frac{3}{64}$

Comment: Perfect answer.